# Measure spaces proof

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

This theorem comes from the book Real Analysis by Folland

Note: $M$ is a $\sigma$-algebra

Suppose that $(X,M,\mu)$ is a measure space. Let $\mathcal{N} = \{N\in M: \mu(N) = 0\}$ and $\bar{M} = \{E\cup F: E\in M  \ \ \text{and} \ \ F\subset N \ \ \text{for some} \ \ N\in\mathcal{N}\}$. Then $\bar{M}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, and there is a unique extention $\bar{\mu}$ of $\mu$ to a complete measure on $\bar{M}$

I believe I need to first show that since $M$ and $\mathcal{N}$ are closed under countable unions then so is $\bar{M}$, but I am not exactly sure how to show this. Then, once I have proven that $\bar{M}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra and given how they defined $\mathcal{N}$ then there must be a unique $\bar{\mu}$ that is a complete measure on $\bar{M}$. I am trying to not look at the proof in the book and do this on my own but I just need some help with the finer details, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Take a countable family in $\overline{M}$. Look at $$\bigcup_{k = 1}^\infty (E_k \cup F_k) = \Biggl(\bigcup_{k = 1}^\infty E_k \Biggr) \cup \Biggl(\bigcup_{k = 1}^\infty F_k\Biggr).$$

Comment: @DanielFischer I realized I do not understand the answer below. Do you have any idea how to prove this theorem?

Comment: Which part(s) have you problems with?

Comment: Well to prove that $\overline{M}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra we have to first show that it is an algebra i.e. that it is closed under unions and complements. This is where I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: You don't have to prove that it's closed under finite unions separately. The case of finite unions is subsumed under the case of countable unions (to show $A_1, A_2 \in \overline{M} \implies A_1 \cup A_2 \in \overline{M}$ if you have the result on countable unions, let $B_1 = A_1$ and $B_k = A_2$ for $k \geqslant 2$). Also, you need to show that $\varnothing \in \overline{M}$ - or that $X \in \overline{M}$, with the closure under complements the two are equivalent. But $\varnothing \in M$, and we have $M \subset \overline{M}$, so $\varnothing \in \overline{M}$.

Comment: Could you provide an answer? I am still confused on what we need to show

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what you're confused about, so I don't know what I should write what isn't in the answer. Can you explain more what you find unclear?

Comment: What specific points must I show for $\overline{M}$ to be a $\sigma$-algebra

Comment: You need to show that $\overline{M}$ contains the empty set, and that $\overline{M}$ is closed under complement and countable unions. In formulae:  i) $\varnothing \in \overline{M}$, ii) $A \in \overline{M} \implies (X\setminus A) \in \overline{M}$, iii) $A_n \in \overline{M}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ implies $\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} A_n \in \overline{M}$. That's the definition of a $\sigma$-algebra, and you have to check whether these conditions are satisfied by $\overline{M}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Claim 1**: $\bar{\mathcal{M}}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

**Proof:** Since $\emptyset \in \mathcal{N}$ and $\mathcal{M}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, we have that $X \cup \emptyset = X \in \bar{\mathcal{M}}$.

Next, suppose that $E \in \bar{\mathcal{M}}$.  So $E = A \cup F$ where $A \in \mathcal{M}$ and $F \subset N$ for $N \in \mathcal{N}$.

Then $X \setminus E = X \setminus(A \cup F) = (X \setminus A) \cap (X \setminus N) \cup ((X \setminus A)\cap (N \setminus F))$.

Now $(X \setminus A) \cap (X \setminus N) \in \mathcal{M}$, while $(X \setminus A) \cap (N \setminus F) \subset N$.

This shows that $X \setminus E \in \bar{\mathcal{M}}$.

Finally, let $E_j \in \bar{\mathcal{M}}$ for $j = 1, 2, \dots$.  Then for each $j$, write $E_j = A_j \cup F_j$, where $F_j \subset N_j$ and $\mu(N_j) = 0$.

Then $ \displaystyle \bigcup_j E_j = \bigcup_j (A_j \cup F_j) = 
\\ \bigcup_j A_j \cup \bigcup_j F_j$

Notice that $\bigcup_j F_j \subset \bigcup_j N_j$ and $\mu(\bigcup_j N_j) = 0$.

So we have have that $\bigcup_j E_j \in \bar{\mathcal{M}}$.

This shows that $\bar{\mathcal{M}}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

Next, let's define $\bar{\mu}(E) = \mu(A)$ where $E = A \cup F$ as above.  You need to show that this definition does not depend on the choice of decomposition of $E$.

Comment: Can you explain the $X\setminus E$ part?

Comment: So $E = A \cup F$, and we have that there's an $N \in \mathcal{N}$ such that $F \subset N$.  So $X \setminus E = X \setminus (A \cup F)$.  So if $x \in X \setminus (A \cup F)$, then certainly $x \in X$ and $x \not \in A$.  Now it's possible that $x \not \in N$, in which case we're fine.  Or it's alright if $x \in N$ so long as $x \not \in F$.